# How to get values of voltage and current at different times ,using pspice?

Tags: voltage, current, spice, simulation

This is probably a really trivial question nevertheless it has had me confused for a while. I'm trying to solve a circuit using PSpice and for that matter I need to get the values of different node voltages and a couple of currents at different times. How can I do it? Please be as thorough as possible because I'm a newbie.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the use of PC software.

Answer (score 1):

Transient response simulation will give you the node voltages and branch currents at all times during your simulation. As long as your "different times" fall within the simulation time, they will be available.